# Is it possible to receive push messages addressed to different registration ids within a single app?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

How can I enable my application to receive GCM push messages for multiple registration ids? Is this possible?

I'm doing this, because I have an exported `Activity` wherein I am listening for the push to arrive.

Comment: Exported Activity? You mean an open intent? Why would you need a different id? If such an Activity gets called, your first app with that exported activity would still get called.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk An exported Activity [exported flag set to true](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exported). The same thing the Facebook SDK does when you have their app installed and you try to login with Facebook from within another app, it calls its login `Activity`.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk It's not a problem if the app with the exported `Activity` gets called. What I want is to be able to receive multiple push messages to different registration ids using the registration id provided by the second app.

Comment: You could `receiving messages from multi-senders`, check out here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#receiving-messages-from-multi-senders However, I dont think you can have multiple registration ids for just one device. The `InstanceId` is kind of identifier for each device.